# How to programmatically enable and restore the Windows Language Bar?

Tags: c++, delphi, winapi

How can I programmatically enable the language bar in Windows? (XP, Vista, 7, 8) Subsequently, how can I make the language bar float (undock from the taskbar so it is floating?

Some language keyboards add additional buttons to the language bar. In default mode when the language bar is docked in the taskbar these additional buttons are not visible.

Is there a way that my application could make the language bar float so that the user would see the additional buttons?

Comment: Isn't that something that the user does?

Comment: It usually is. If the user doesn't know the additional buttons are there then s/he is not going to know to use the additional features. If I restore it, the user could see that there are more buttons and then dock it back if the user wants.

Comment: A few secs ago TLama added and deleted a comment pointing at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/105cec4e-35d9-4357-9433-8f159232093a/finding-an-api-using-which-i-could-hideshow-language-bar-running-in-task-bar. The page has a comment at the end which points to ITfLangBarMgr interface in Text Service Framework. ITfLangBarMgr::ShowFloating looks like it could do it and work for me. How can I credit TLama for this?

Comment: If I was the user of this program, I'd be very annoyed if it did something like this.

Comment: Hmmm okay, how can I tell/show the user in an un-annoying way that there are more buttons in the language bar and he should undock the bar to see them?

Comment: Put it in your documentation would be my advice. I don't think it's your place to be modifying settings that belong to the user. It's somewhat akin to changing which icons are visible in the notification area, or making the taskbar larger. The user is going to loathe you for that!

Comment: Ok I don't want them to loathe me and I don't want to annoy them. Nobody reads the documentation though. Can I point a balloon popup at the language bar and tell the user to undock it to see more? If so how can I get the coordinates of the lang bar?

Comment: This is something that all developers struggle with. When you pop up the balloon, the user will just close it without reading it! If a user doesn't want to read the documentation, and heed the advice, then they won't. Anyway, I'm way off topic now! I'll stop there.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I shall think about the doc or a popup. If you put it as an answer I'd choose that. For anybody reading this, you can find the langbar by searching for TF_FloatingLangBar_WndTitle. Its same whether docked or floating.

Comment: I cannot really put that as an answer since it does not answer your question.